# jquery iframe problems with firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, browser, iframe, mozilla

im loading several iframes on one page which are hidden until you load them through a click via jquery. then they are to supposed to show up. it works all fine in chrome and safari but firefox will not show the iframes content.

it works if you reload the iframe again. then the content will show up.

here a link to the page: http://www.purpurstyling.com/portfolio/styling/

i tried already delaying loading the iframes until the dom is ready but this is not working as well.

how is it possible to fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what happens is that because the `<iframe>` is `display: none;` this means that Gecko doesn't bother calculating the frame size and the slider code doesn't know what to do with a 0×0 window. If you use `visibility: hidden;` instead it should work.